# Google Cloud Datastore python local dev can't find datastore module

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I followed the instructions given in this [Google Cloud Datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/datastore/cloud-client) tutorial in python to test [Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries) locally.  When I run this code:

```python
from google.cloud import datastore

client = datastore.Client()
```

I get the following error:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud'
```

I installed `google-cloud-datastore`, yet the problem persists.

It seems like a missing dependency problem, yet I don't know what module to install since I installed everything in the [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/datastore/cloud-client/requirements.txt) file.

Comment: It sounds like the `google-cloud-datastore` either didn't get properly installed or isn't installed in the same environment you're trying to import it in. Can you include the output of `pip freeze`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `google-cloud-datastore` either didn't get properly installed or isn't installed in the same environment you're trying to import it from.

From an empty environment, I can install the `google-cloud-datastore` package, and then be able to import it:

```
/tmp $ python -m venv env

/tmp $ source env/bin/activate

(env) /tmp $ pip freeze

(env) /tmp $ pip install google-cloud-datastore==1.7.0
Collecting google-cloud-datastore==1.7.0
  ...lots of output...
Successfully installed cachetools-2.1.0 certifi-2018.8.24 chardet-3.0.4 google-api-core-1.4.0 google-auth-1.5.1 google-cloud-core-0.28.1 google-cloud-datastore-1.7.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.5.3 grpcio-1.15.0 idna-2.7 protobuf-3.6.1 pyasn1-0.4.4 pyasn1-modules-0.2.2 pytz-2018.5 requests-2.19.1 rsa-3.4.2 six-1.11.0 urllib3-1.23

(env) /tmp $ pip freeze
cachetools==2.1.0
certifi==2018.8.24
chardet==3.0.4
google-api-core==1.4.0
google-auth==1.5.1
google-cloud-core==0.28.1
google-cloud-datastore==1.7.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
grpcio==1.15.0
idna==2.7
protobuf==3.6.1
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.19.1
rsa==3.4.2
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.23

(env) /tmp $ python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jul 30 2018, 11:52:05)
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.cloud import datastore
>>>
```

Comment: I ran the script you show above and it worked for me.  As you said, it seems like `google-cloud-datastore` wasn't properly installed.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Please accept the answer if this solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a missing (or broken) dependency problem.  It's fixed by installing `google-cloud-storage`.

```
pip install google-cloud-storage
```

Google should have added this to `datastore`'s dependency tree to make our lives easier.

Comment: This is not correct, please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52299176/328036)